# Importing .obj from 3DS to Blender distortion issue

Tags: export, import, unreal-engine

I want to export a mesh from 3DS to Blender, I currently use .obj format.

My screenshots are taken from Unreal but the issue is the same on Blender.
Here is my 2 floors superposed, one is selected in yellow

[image: 2 Floors superposition]

My problem is that when I use .obj,  only my height is incorrect:
[image: walls]

[image: windows]

As you can see, my lenght and width are similar, but my windows, walls, door have a bad height. If I check on 3DS, both of my floors have the same height and everything is good.

Do you have an idea why ? Thank you.

Comment: Could you show screenshot of these objects before exporting ? I don't think I see what do you mean by "bad height". The only suggestion would be to [apply transforms](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/transform/transform_control/reset_object_transformations.html?highlight=apply%20transforms#apply-object-transformations) before exporting.

Comment: If the issue is the same in both Blender and Unreal, it means it comes from 3DSMax exporter somehow. Could imagine e.g. some kind of weird transform applied to walls to get them the same height as windows, that does not get applied during OBJ export, or something like that…